# Use column if it exists, another if doesn't in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a number of SQL Server databases (different versions from 2012 to 2019). The schema in each one is very similar but not exactly the same.  For example, there's table `ORDERS`, which has about 50 columns - and one column is called differently in two different databases:

- in DB1: `select p_user from orders`
- in DB2: `select userpk from orders`

Note that I showed two databases above, but there are actually more than 20 - some are DB1 type, the others are DB2 type

I can't do much about these differences - they are historic - and changing the schema to match is not an option.

I want to be able to run the same SQL statement against all of these databases at once.  I'd like to write the query in such a way that it would use one column if it exists and another if it doesn't.  For example:

```
select
    case
        when COL_LENGTH('orders', 'p_user') IS NOT NULL
    then
        orders.p_user
    else
        orders.userpk
    end
from orders
```

This unfortunately doesn't work, as SQL server seems to try to evaluate both results regardless of whether the condition is true or false.  The same thing happens if I use `IIF` function.

If I simply run

```
select
    case
        when COL_LENGTH('orders', 'p_user') IS NOT NULL
    then
        'orders.p_user'
    else
        'orders.userpk'
    end
```

then I do get the correct string, which means my condition is correct.

How can I formulate the SQL statement to use one or the other column based on whether the first one exists?

Comment: Why not create a view to unify the schema differences? Having to rewrite every single query is not just massively burdensome, it has performance implications as well. It *is* possible to write a query that refers to a non-existent column, by abusing the way name resolution works, but this should not be done unless there's really no other way -- even dynamic query generation is preferable to that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I don't own the databases nor have any write access to them. I can't create any columns, views or anything else.

Comment: Will they allow creating a new database? You could create views in that with three-part naming (`SELECT x AS y FROM legacydb.dbo.OldTable`). It would take up "no room" since it needn't actually contain any data of its own.

Comment: I can't create anything on their DB servers - nor can connect to the database from anything other than a very restricted shell on the db server itself.

Comment: SQL compiles and validates the entire statement before it runs it; it's not a programming language. In your query you reference both`orders.p_user` and `orders.userpk`; it doesn't matter if you'll never use that value, it'll error as the column doesn't exist.

Comment: I suspect I'll have to do this with dynamic sql... I'm playing around with that now...

Comment: The best solution is honestly to fix things up client-side in that case -- detect the scheme and generate queries according to the actual column names, using a template with a placeholder name. In other words, create "views" of your own.

Comment: If you can't create or alter anything, then I'm suspecting that there's only the route of Dynamic Sql left.  If you really can't even add views anyway.

Comment: The non-dynamic trick for this to abuse name resolution logic: `SELECT T.ID, V.DoesNotExist FROM T CROSS JOIN (SELECT NULL) _(DoesNotExist) CROSS APPLY (SELECT DoesNotExist FROM T) V` will pick `DoesNotExist` from `T` if it exists, and `NULL` otherwise (you can plug in another column there). Doing this in every single one of your queries is a massive pain, decreases maintainability and has potential performance issues, so I mention it only for completeness.

Comment: Also, the above is actually not correct as-is (the `CROSS JOIN` and `CROSS APPLY` take the entire table and result in way more rows than you want); the correct version would do proper joins. I can't remember the correct version since I didn't invent the trick. :-)

Comment: correct version is here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66741/why-cant-i-use-a-case-statement-to-see-if-a-column-exists-and-not-select-from-i/66755#66755

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change anything then your best (and maybe only) option is to use dynamic SQL. A query will only compile if all parts can be resolved at compile time (before anything runs) - which is why e.g. this will not compile:

```
IF COL_LENGTH('orders', 'p_user') IS NOT NULL THEN
    select p_user from orders
ELSE
    select userpk as p_user from orders
END
```

But this will work:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

IF COL_LENGTH('orders', 'p_user') IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET @SQL = 'select p_user from orders'
ELSE
    SET @SQL = 'select userpk as p_user from orders'
END

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your tables by adding a computed column:

```
alter table db1..orders
    add statuspk as (p_status);
```

(Or choose the other name.)

Then, your queries will just work without adding unnecessary complication to queries.

Comment: I did say that changing the schema is not an option. I don't own these database and do not have permission to make any changes.  I have read-only access to them all.

Comment: Use Dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table orders1(colA int, colB int, colABC int);
insert into orders1 values(1, 2, 3);
go
create table orders2(colA int, colB int, colKLM int);
insert into orders2 values(5, 6, 7);
go
create table orders3(colA int, colB int, colXYZ int);
insert into orders3 values(10, 11, 12);
go


select colA, colB, vcolname as [ABC_KLM_XYZ] 
from
(
select *, 
(select o.* for xml path(''), elements, type).query('
/*[local-name() = ("colABC", "colKLM", "colXYZ")][1]
').value('.', 'int') as vcolname
from orders1 as o
) as src;

select colA, colB, vcolname as [ABC_KLM_XYZ] 
from
(
select *, 
(select o.* for xml path(''), elements, type).query('
/*[local-name() = ("colABC", "colKLM", "colXYZ")][1]
').value('.', 'int') as vcolname
from orders2 as o
) as src;

select colA, colB, vcolname as [ABC_KLM_XYZ] 
from
(
select *, 
(select o.* for xml path(''), elements, type).query('
/*[local-name() = ("colABC", "colKLM", "colXYZ")][1]
').value('.', 'int') as vcolname
from orders3 as o
) as src;
go

drop table orders1
drop table orders2
drop table orders3
go
```

Comment: As I stated in the question and multiple comments, I do not have write access to the database and thus cannot create anything.  I only have read-only access to run queries.

Comment: `select count(distinct vcolname)
from
(
select *, 
(select o.* for xml path(''), elements, type).query('
/*[local-name() = ("p_user", "userpk")][1]
').value('.', 'int') as vcolname
from orders as o
) as src;`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using dynamic sql like so:

```
declare @query nvarchar(1000)
set @query  =  concat(
'select count(distinct ', (case when COL_LENGTH('orders', 'p_user') IS NOT NULL then 'orders.p_user' else 'orders.userpk' end), ')
from orders'
);
execute sp_executesql @query
```

This solved my immediate issue.